# Custom colormap and change user range to plot 2D function not defined on the whole range

Tags: python, numpy, colormap

I would like to plot a map of 2D function f(x,y) where f(x,y) is not defined on the whole range of x in [0;1] and y in [0;1]. 1.5

I'm using imshow function to plot the map. However the colormap takes into account the data equal to -1. I would like to rescale the colormap and change color assigned for -1.

My code: The data are in ascii file using matrix format

```
filename = "map_chi_h_rho_disc2.txt"
raw_data = np.loadtxt(filename)
zeta = raw_data[:1] # first line
zeta = zeta[0] # array of array with 1 element to 1 array
zeta = zeta[1:] # remove first element
eta = np.array(np.transpose(raw_data)[0]) # first column
eta = eta [1:] # remove first element
data = raw_data[1:] # remove first line
data = data[:,1:] # remove first column
data = np.transpose(data)
etab = 0
etae = eta[-1]
zetab  = 0
zetae = zeta[-1]

fig = plt.figure()
cmap2 = plt.get_cmap("jet")
im1= imshow(data, interpolation='bicubic', origin='lower',cmap = cmap2 , extent=(etab,etae,zetab,zetae),aspect='auto')
# limit of cmap
climitb = 1.5
climite = 2.5
v = np.linspace(climitb, climite, 5, endpoint=True)
cbar =fig.colorbar(im1,ticks=v)
plt.clim(climitb,climite)
plt.show()
```

And the resulting figure:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLcrw.png]

First I would like to change the dark blue color to white color and second, to rescale the colorbar

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rescale the color map by setting vmin, vmax as you did :

```
plt.clim(vmin, vmax) # use dark blue for vmin -> red for vmax
```

To "clear" the other values (under and over your defined range) you can then use cmap functions to precise the colors to apply :

```
cmap.set_under('w') # will use white for values under vmin
cmap.set_over('k') # will use black for values over vmax
```